# Wave equation with infinite time

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact domain with smooth boundary. Let $f \in H^1_\delta((0,\infty)\times \partial \Omega)$, where
$$ \|f\|_{H^1_\delta}^2= \|f\|^2_{L^2_\delta}+\|Df\|^2_{L^2_\delta}$$
and
$$ \|f\|_{L^2_\delta((0,\infty)\times \partial \Omega)}^2= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\partial \Omega} |f(t,x)|^2(1+t^2)^{\delta}\,dt\,d\sigma$$

Consider the wave equation

\begin{equation}\label{pf0}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
\partial^2_tu-\Delta u=0\,\quad &\text{on $(0,\infty)\times \Omega$},
\\
u=f\,\quad &\text{on $(0,\infty)\times \partial \Omega$,}\\
\end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I think that provided some suitable decay properties for $u$ at infinity one should be able to find a existence and uniqueness of solutions $u \in H^1_{\delta'}((0,\infty)\times \Omega)$ for some $\delta'$ that depends on $\delta$.

I wonder if this type of Cauchy problem for the wave equation with data vanishing at infinity rather than at time zero has been studied systematically. If not, what is the best way to approach this problem.
Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by $H^1_\delta$ ?

Comment: Just that the function has some decay in the time variable. This has been formulated in the definition.